# Change Value of Date Input With PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have this input:

```
<input type="date" name="datin" value="">
```

I need to change the value of this input to be the value of $row['eventoDatIn'] which is also a date with the format YYYY-MM-DD.

I've tried echoing the value in 3 ways:

```
<input type="date" name="datin" value="
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo date($row['eventoDatIn']); 
}
}
?>">
```

This:

```
<input type="date" name="datin" value="
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo date(htmlspecialchars ($row['eventoDatIn'])); 
}
}
?>">
```

And this:

```
<input type="date" name="datin" value="
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo (htmlspecialchars ($row['eventoDatIn']));  
}
}
?>">
```

The input always ends up just showing the default mm/dd/yyyy value.
Is this a problem with the date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope the problem is in your coding, you missed first parameter of `date` function which is `format specifier`and also second parameter is `value in second`, try below code :-

```
<input type="date" name="datin" value="
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['eventoDatIn'])); // check the change 
}
}
?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the [`date` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is actually the date *format*. Characters that are not valid in a format, are printed as-is.

So basically you are echoing the current time in a format that doesn't contain any valid formatting options, so in result, the 'format' (which is actually your date) is outputted literally.

Try

```
echo date('Y-M-d', $row['eventoDatIn']);
```

PS: You said 'I have a date in this format', but I hope the date is actually a real date (timestamp) in the database. If it is a formatted string, you may have to convert it to a timestamp first. If possible do that in the database and store your dates and times as actual dates and times rather than strings.

In MySQL you can [convert dates to UNIX_TIMESTAMPS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), which can be read by PHP:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(YourDateField) AS TheDate FROM YourTable
```

Comment: That didn't work :( but it's probably part of the solution, and this value from $row['eventoDatIn'] is stored in the DB as a DATE and it looks like this: 2015-05-23.

Comment: Use the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function inside the query to return the date as a timestamp which can be used by PHP.